# How do I call a static method when I press a button?

Tags: c#, string, static

Currently, I have this all laid out:

```
public static string Encrypt<T>(string anything)
{
 //Stuff can go here
}
```

When I press a button, I want to be able to run ALL the code in Encrypt. Is it possible to do this, and if it is, how can I?

Comment: So handle the button's `Click` event and call the method. It's not difficult. What have you tried, and what hasn't worked about it?

Comment: I've tried changing it to a public static void, then calling it with Encrypt<T>();, Encrypt<>();, Encrypt();, etc.. As you MAY be able to tell, I'm just beginning with C#, and haven't been able to find it on google or anything.

Comment: If there's not a reason for the generic <T>, get rid of it.  It's confusing you.  Should be easy after that.

Comment: You need to pass it a string and also give it a generic type. I have no idea what the method is supposed to do, but if the `<T>` isn't there for any good reason, take it out.

Comment: @JohnArlen it's used later in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose your aspx button is

```
<asp:Button runat="server" text="Encrypt" id="btnencrypt" onclick="btnencrypt_Click" />
```

Your server side event will be like this:

```
protected void btnencrypt_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    // Supposing that the Encrypt method is not in the current class.
    OtherClass.Encrypt(anystring);
}
```

If the Encrypt method is in the same class then you can directly write the method name like:

```
Encrypt(anystring);
```

You don't need the .
So your Encrypt method will be like:

```
public static string Encrypt(string inputstring)
{
    //Encryption code.
}
```

Hope u get your answer from this...

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your button in your ASPX could be written this way:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" text="Encrypt" onclick="encrypt_click" />
```

Let's say the cs page behind your ASPX page (Code-behind) could be written like

```
protected void encrypt_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Encrypt(text);
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?